# php7.2-gd can't find package (tried everything)

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, php-gd

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and php7.2 but can't install php7.2-gd
I need to install package php7.2-g

when i run apt-get install php7.2-gd it says that:

> E: Unable to locate package php7.2-gd
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-gd'

I added repository add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php and did apt-update
but when i use apt-cache search php7 it doesn't show me that i have php7.2-gd and of course i can't install it.

Maybe problem in ubuntu 14.04 but not sure

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.2-gd
```